# Missing Client IP in postfix Received header

Tags: postfix

I just noticed my postfix setup has been having a problem for some time now.

When receiving (some) mail from German freemail provider web.de, the following headers are found inside the mail postfix passes on to the MDA:

```
Received: from mout.web.de (unknown)
        by mail.<mydomain>.de(Postfix 2.9.6/8.13.0) with SMTP id unknown
        Wed, 29 Jan 2014 09:00:14 +0100
        (envelope-from <...@web.de>
Received: from 3capp-webde-bs39.server.lan ([172.19.170.39]) by
 mriweb.server.lan (mriweb002) with ESMTP (Nemesis) id
 ***** for <...@....de>; Wed, 29 Jan 2014 09:01:01
 +0100
Received: from [##.###.##.###] by 3capp-webde-bs39.server.lan with HTTP; Wed
 Jan 29 09:01:01 CET 2014
```

This is what's in the logs:

```
postfix/smtpd[16230]: connect from mout.web.de[212.227.17.11]
postfix/smtpd[16230]: 5C17E14C10A6: client=mout.web.de[212.227.17.11]
postfix/cleanup[16238]: 5C17E14C10A6: message-id=<trinity-b7f12c80-a158-43f9-8266-583a7b0533bd-############@3capp-webde-bs39>
postfix/qmgr[4490]: 5C17E14C10A6: from=<...@web.de>, size=6402, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/smtpd[16230]: disconnect from mout.web.de[212.227.17.11]
postfix/lmtp[16242]: 5C17E14C10A6: to=<...@....de>, relay=mail.<mydomain>.de[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=1, delays=0.81/0/0/0.22, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <...@....de> qO51H+K06FKAPwAAsCbVSQ Saved)
postfix/qmgr[4490]: 5C17E14C10A6: removed
```

The problem is that spamassassin now tries to do RBL checks on the first hop IP, because the IP address from last hop isn't available and the second one is a private network. First hop is of course dynamic, so all mail gets marked as spam.

When trying to reproduce this from my own web.de account the lines look like:

```
Received: from mout.web.de (mout.web.de [212.227.17.12])
        by mail.<mydomain>.de (Postfix) with ESMTP id ***
        for <info@....de>; Sat,  8 Feb 2014 17:26:11 +0100 (CET)
```

This is exactly the outcome I expect.

Any clues as to why postfix doesn't put the client IP in the Received header?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's in the server logs?

Comment: ... got to learn that I can't put log contents in comments... see OP

Comment: Have you ever bin able to fix that?

Comment: I haven't... it's still causing issues sometimes, but I learned to live with those...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is somewhere in spamass-milter (search for "Received: from" in [spamass-milter.cpp](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/spamass-milt/spamass-milter.cpp?revision=1.100&root=spamass-milt&view=markup)). This is somehow due to the fact that the milter runs before the incoming SMTP connection is closed and postfix has not written its Received-Headers yet and spamass-milter needs to do some magic which appears to be broken in some cases.

Unfortunately, I do not have the necessary time or knowledge to debug this issue in spamass-milter futher, so I just dropped milter completely and continue to use SpamAssassin the "old-style" way:

```
# master.cf
dovecot-spamass   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -u ${recipient} -e /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -a ${original_recipient} -d ${user}@${nexthop}

# main.cf
virtual_transport=dovecot-spamass
```

Compared to the milter/lmtp setup this is documented as being a bit slower and it doesn't give you the possibility to reject bounce messages that exceed a certain SpamAssassin score within the SMTP session (which is fine for me).

Thanks to Julian for [helping to debug this](https://twitter.com/julian24/status/791910215834664960).

Comment: I just had this issue again, found my own question from 5 years ago and noticed you answered it. Here, have a checkmark ;)

Answer (score 1):

"look, i fixed it..." - https://bz.apache.org/SpamAssassin/show_bug.cgi?id=7909

Comment: Nice bughunt. Please add some more details to this answer so it can stand alone. Link-only answers rot over time. I've lost several of mine that way.